# (Variation of Topic Challenge) Game suggestion: Find the gem!

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge, voting

In order to increase participation in voting, I suggest a variation of a topic challenge, namely a *game suggestion: Find the gem!*

- I invite you to find an underrated answer and write a link to it as an answer of this meta post. Also explain in a few words why this answer is worth other users attention.
- If you agree with other user's post that the link is worth an upvote, also upvote this meta answer.
- You can't suggest your own answer.

At the end of November, we'll see who made the best suggestion (difference between score before the game and after the game).

Comment: That's not an easy challenge: I mostly only look at older questions if they *don't* have an answer, and if I come across a good answer by chance I upvote it and move on. But I'll see if I can find something.

Comment: @PiedPiper, thanks for your feedback. I understand that for most users, participation means writing answers, that's why I suggest other ways of participating: reviewing old questions/answers and voting.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this [answer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/3705/3260) to the question **How can I find out in which movies/games a musical work was featured?**

It only had 1 point when I saw it and I think it is very useful and well formatted.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this [answer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/8304/2pac-vs-the-notorious-b-i-g-objective-comparisons/8306#8306) to the question **2Pac vs. The Notorious B.I.G. - objective comparisons**.

It only had 2 points (I'd already voted) and has a great work of gathering info.