# Revival of the topic challenges?

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

Back in the day — the day I like to refer to as 2017 and 2019 — there were a couple of "Topic Challenges"

- [First Ever Music Fans Stack Topic Challenge - Jam Bands](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/352/9288)
- [Music Fans Topic Challenge #2 - Dancing](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/403/9288)

and a variation thereof

- [(Variation of Topic Challenge) Game suggestion: Find the gem!](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/536/9288).

These types of challenges deserve a comeback, or at least a chance for a comeback, in these more modern times — times I like to refer to as "2022–2023".

Comment: Good on you for taking the initiative :) The last time it was proposed to revive the topic challenges the idea was shot down because apparently there would be no point without first taking care of the more pressing quality problems, i.e. the identification questions. Now that those have been declared off-topic, hopefully there will be greater support for this activity.

Comment: A separate thread should probably be opened for taking suggestions and voting on them.

Comment: It's a good idea that didn't get received well.  As you can see from your links, I proposed the challenge, and then won it due to lack of questions submitted.  :-)

Comment: @JohnnyBones Yeah, I saw that the previous challenges didn't get much participation. But I'm game for trying it again.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I suppose it's worth adding that while I'm game, this post has received an average of less than one view per day (20 views in 21 days) and one upvote. Less than auspicious, I suppose. Still game, though.

Comment: This needs some support from the moderator team to work. At minimum, the ([meta-tag:featured]) tag should be placed on it for greater visibility. And it's completely natural for the first few runs of such an event to not be a success. One can take a look at how [literature.se] have been running theirs to get some idea about how this can be done, and what difficulties one has to overcome.

Comment: Will this be happening then? @JohnnyBones

Comment: @taylor.2317 IMO, it needs more support from the general user base to make it worthwhile.

Comment: Would it be possible to display to each user a pop-up where they can answer a poll on whether they would take place? also, the [tag:featured] tag should be on any of the posts...

Comment: @taylor.2317 The featured tag should be a simple matter, but I don't know about the poll.

Answer (score 1):

Let's keep a list of suggested topic challenge topics here.

#### Topic Challenge Topic Suggestions

- The `pick-a-decade`s (e.g., "The 1930s", "The 2000s", "The 1750s", ...)
- Grammy Awards (or other music-related awards)
- Questions about music from X-Woods (Hollywood, Bollywood, Nollywood, ...)

#### Past Topic Challenge Topics

- Jam Bands
- Dancing
- Identify and vote for great posts